# Como buscar a Session no Hibernate 5.2.3.Final

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, cdi

olá!
Galera estou alterando meu Hibernate da versão 4.3.8.Final para 5.2.3.Final.
Agora não estou conseguindo buscar a Session do Hibernate como fazia antes, assim:

`(Session) manager.unwrap(Session.class);`

Dá erro de Cast

`:java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.weldx.persistence.EntityManager$1993463486$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy cannot be cast to org.hibernate.Session`

Alguém tem alguma ideia? Pelo que vi na documentação parece que deveria ser da mesma forma.
 https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-unwrap

Comment: Pelo que pude perceber tem algo a ver com o CDI que estou usando, pois fim uns testes em outro programa sem e funciona...

Answer (score 2):

Meu problema era com o CDI. Tenho um método produtor de entityManager que estava anotado com @RequestScoped. Até na versão anterior do Hibernate tudo funcionava, deta forma. Depois de procurar muito achei algo parecido falando para mudar para @Dependent e não é que resolveu.

```
@Produces @Dependent //@RequestScoped estava assim até alterar a versão do Hibernate
    public EntityManager createEntityManager() {
        return factory.createEntityManager();
    }

    public void closeEntityManager(@Disposes EntityManager manager) {
        manager.close();
    }
```

[Solução](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WELD-1498)

Comment: Estava agora fazendo uns testes neste `@Dependent` e não gostei, ele não fecha mais a EntityManager no método com o `@Disposes` E ainda passa diversas vezes no `@Produces` em vez de uma única por requisição. Tá estranho...não entendi ainda o motivo de não funcionar com o `@RequestScoped`, se alguém souber me fala.

Answer (score 1):

Caso não tenha resolvido...
Resolvi assim:

```
@RequestScoped
public Session createEntityManager() {
    return (Session) this.factory.createEntityManager();
}

public void closeEntityManager(@Disposes Session manager) {
    manager.close();
}
```

Se olhar o interface Session do hibernate, vais ver que agora é também implementa EntityManager, dai por baixo dos panos dá "tilt" no Weld.
Na verdade o Tiago da Algaworks que foi mais a fundo nisso, apenas usei a mesma ideia dele

```
public interface Session extends SharedSessionContract, EntityManager, HibernateEntityManager, AutoCloseable
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and solved it like this:

change

```
    Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class);
```

to

```
    TargetInstanceProxy<?> proxy = 
               (TargetInstanceProxy<?>) em.unwrap(Session.class);
    Session session = (Session) proxy.weld_getTargetInstance();
```

Session is

```
     org.hibernate.Session
```

TargetInstanceProxy is

```
     org.jboss.weld.interceptor.util.proxy.TargetInstanceProxy
```

Comment: Traduza para português, por favor.